What is the process of working with a sensitivity reader?
Every fiction story has some characters that don't match the author's identity. I know the first step of representing a character from a different background is research, and I'm vaguely aware that published authors also employ sensitivity readers. The podcasts and writing resources I've found that mention them don't go into much detail, though.
What is the process of working with a sensitivity reader? How much would an indie publisher pay a sensitivity reader? How do publishers decide what types of sensitivity readers to ask to read a book and when do they become involved in the process?
What happens when they catch something offensive or inaccurate? Should I be worried that I would offend a sensitivity reader if I touch on a controversial topic?

Making a sensitivity reader takes a lot of time and sand paper

The process of sensitivity reading is quite simple and straightforward: A copy of your manuscript is given to a sensitivity reader. That person reads the book and returns it to you or the publisher with suggested changes. You decide which changes you want to make and what you want to leave unchanged. The pubisher decides whether the changes you made are enough for them to go forward with publishing your book. Consequently the book is published or further changes are demanded, which you can decide to make or forgo the publication.

Hi. The process you describe seemed to be set in place by publishers, as a way to correct a manuscript after it's been written. But a conscientious writer should probably take some steps before and while writing, rather than wait until they have completed their manuscript. Especially so if the topic of concern is central to the story.

@Stef The present question asked about the process of working with a sensitivity reader. That's what I described in my answer. Sensitivity readers aren't involved in the writing of a text. If you want to know how do avoid offensive content or stereotypes during writing, you could ask a question about that. Or browse the existing questions, as that has been asked before, multiple times.

You obviously know more about all this than the person who asked the question, but you're choosing to not mention it because of the wording of the question? Okay... Have a nice day.

This answer assumes that someone is an author working with a big publishing house. What about an author who is self-publishing or someone who is an editor at a publishing house?

@TMuffin My answer takes both options into consideration. Just delete all sentences that contain "publisher" and you have the answer for a self-publisher. The editor is a representative of the publisher and not a third party. Just replace publisher with editor.
